# what type of data contained by pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-address

I wrote the following code

```
int num =   3;
int *ptr = &num;

cout << *ptr << " " << ptr << endl;
```

And got the following output.

```
3 0x7fff5fbff43c
```

I wanted to know what is the type of data is this.

> 0x7fff5fbff43c

is it

a. signed float data

b. signed integer data

c. unsigned float data

d. unsigned integer data

e. signed character data

Comment: f. none of the above

Answer (score 6):

It's none of these - it is a pointer to integer, a beast that is different from any type that has the word "data" in its description.

The `0x7fff5fbff43c` is merely a *numeric interpretation* of a pointer as an unsigned integer number printed out in base-16.

Comment: so can we safely assume that its option d?

Comment: @itsaboutcode Although printing pointers as an unsigned hex integer is the most common way to visualize them for human readers, it is technically incorrect to say that a pointer *is* an unsigned integer. The right answer would be "this is a pointer represented in the form of an unsigned integer number in hex notation", so in a sense, "d" is the least incorrect choice (but it is still incorrect).

Answer (score 3):

The type of the data is `int *`. It is not any of the things you mentioned. You may be able to cast it to one of those; however, whether you can do this is undefined and may vary between platforms and compilers.

For display, ostream's `<<` will convert to a string. This string does not correspond to a type directly; `operator<<` calls into `ostream` functions to pass in character data, either as separate characters, a bytestring, or a combination thereof.

Answer (score -1):

It represents a memory address, not a variable. So it is untyped. However you can give it an "indirect type" which means that the memory pointed at by this pointer does have a type (so you can have pointers to int's, chars, structures, etc...).

Read up on [indirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection), it's an interesting concept.

Comment: Pointers are not untyped.   They have types.   Pointer types.

Comment: @JamesYoungman they are not "true" types, they are "indirect types" as mentioned in my answer, since they describe the type of the underlying memory pointed at rather than the pointer itself. Let's not fight over semantics though, one can call them pointer types if wanted.

Comment: @Thomas Wrong. `ptr` *is* a variable of type *pointer to int*